# Blender 3.2. How to make a cloth lighter by playing with the settings?

Tags: 3d, blender

My problem is that a made an animation of satisfying cloth, and I made a ball go through the cloth, but

Unfortunately the cloth movement is extremely fast (which is very disappointing).

And I want another way except that you need to animate the rigid body world speed, which I don't want

Here is an image for that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOYnu.png)

Don't think it's slow, if I could upload the animation, you will see how fast it is.

The stuff that I tried (and unfortunately most of them didn't work :( , and I don't know why)

1- Played with the mass of the ball and the cloth, but it looked worse.

2- Applied scale, location and rotation transforms on both objects, and it didn't work either.

3- Scaled the cloth and kept the ball at the same size so maybe it would take more time to fall down, but

Still it's fast.

So Please find me a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above mentioned parameter changes did not yield the result that you like, you may consider lowering the gravity in your scene or slow down the ball's movement (e.g. with key frames) to take away the energy of the system. This should give you a perceptual slow-down of things.